mouse and touchpad xfce different options
I have one old partition with an old xubuntu updated to the 24.04 version, and i have a new partition with a new xubuntu 24.04.
When i launch the xfc4-mouse-settings to configure my touchpad, on the new xubutu some options are missing (like sensibility for exemple)


When i launch xfce4-mouse-settings --version , both are 4.18.4
I read these old post but i am not sure that i am concerned cause i use xfce and not unity... ?
Mouse & Touchpad Separate Settings Missing
mouse and touchpad settings missing
Somedy could help me to recover the options i have on the old one to allow me to set it on the new one ?
thank you very much
(sorry for my poor english)

Might the command referenced in the question be  xfce4-mouse-settings?   xfc4-mouse-settings is not found.

That's ok! Execute
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics 

and all options are recovered ;-)
